# Android Java get onStartCommand method

Tags: java, android, methods, get

Hello I have this inside my MainActivity.java:

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "myText";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
        myDialog = new Dialog(this);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_signin);
        myDialog.setCancelable(false);
        password = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.password);
        myDialog.show();
        Button lbtn = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        lbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence passwordCorrect = "Password correct";
            CharSequence passwordIncorrect = "Password wrong";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            if (password.getText().toString().equals("456")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, passwordCorrect, duration).show();
                // onstartCommand method here
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, passwordIncorrect, duration).show();
                // onstartCommand method here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this in my Kiosk.java:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Stopping service 'KioskService'");
    running = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting service 'KioskService'");
    running = true;
    ctx = this;

    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        do {
            handleKioskMode();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Thread interrupted: 'KioskService'");
            }
        } while (running);
        stopSelf();
    }
});

t.start();
return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
```

}

I want to change the running value inside my onStartCommand which is current true, inside my MainActivity if password equals 456 to false.
How do I make that happen.

Comment: Please clarifiy what is causing your confusion.  From what you present, I can see you have a "password" variable that you reference in onBackPressed(). I assume it's a member variable of your activity.  Because of that assumption, it is also available in onStartCommand().  Obviously you know that, but I have no idea what you are really asking for.

Comment: I just want to change the running variable inisde the onStartCommand method of the Kiosk class if the password condition is true.

Comment: I think Mac_Focha's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

create new Intent(Context, Kiosk.class) and call intent.putExtra(String key, boolean value), then just start your service with Activity.starService(Intent) method